# Get Twitter Followers and following in ios7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, twitter, ios7

i have used Twitter API to get followers and following.

i have write this code.  to get followers and following

```
-(void)getTwitterAccounts
{
    ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    // Create an account type that ensures Twitter accounts are retrieved.
    ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
    // let's request access and fetch the accounts
    [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType
            withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)


    {
                                // check that the user granted us access and there were no errors (such as no accounts added on the users device)
                                if (granted && !error)
                                {
                                    NSArray *accountsArray = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];
                                    if ([accountsArray count] > 1) {
                                        // a user may have one or more accounts added to their device
                                        // you need to either show a prompt or a separate view to have a user select the account(s) you need to get the followers and friends for
                                    } else {
                                        [self getTwitterFriendsForAccount:[accountsArray objectAtIndex:0]];
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    // handle error (show alert with information that the user has not granted your app access, etc.)
                                }
                            }];
}



-(void)getTwitterFriendsForAccount:(ACAccount*)account
{
    // In this case I am creating a dictionary for the account
    // Add the account screen name
    NSMutableDictionary *accountDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:account.username, @"screen_name", nil];
    // Add the user id (I needed it in my case, but it's not necessary for doing the requests)
    [accountDictionary setObject:[[[account dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"properties"]] objectForKey:@"properties"] objectForKey:@"user_id"] forKey:@"user_id"];
    // Setup the URL, as you can see it's just Twitter's own API url scheme. In this case we want to receive it in JSON
    NSURL *followingURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1/friends/ids.json"];
    // Pass in the parameters (basically '.ids.json?screen_name=[screen_name]')
    NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:account.username, @"screen_name", nil];
    // Setup the request
    TWRequest *twitterRequest = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:followingURL
                                                    parameters:parameters
                                                 requestMethod:TWRequestMethodGET];
    // This is important! Set the account for the request so we can do an authenticated request. Without this you cannot get the followers for private accounts and Twitter may also return an error if you're doing too many requests
    [twitterRequest setAccount:account];
    // Perform the request for Twitter friends
    [twitterRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            // deal with any errors - keep in mind, though you may receive a valid response that contains an error, so you may want to look at the response and ensure no 'error:' key is present in the dictionary
        }
        NSError *jsonError = nil;
        // Convert the response into a dictionary
        NSDictionary *twitterFriends = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&jsonError];
        // Grab the Ids that Twitter returned and add them to the dictionary we created earlier
        [accountDictionary setObject:[twitterFriends objectForKey:@"ids"] forKey:@"friends_ids"];
        NSLog(@"%@", accountDictionary);
    }];
}
```

but this code not works

give me error

**NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'**

why this is happening. please help me to sort out this.

Answer (score 4):

Finally i get the solution.

Here is the Solution for get the Twitter Followers and Following Names

First you need to get the Valid Username. and that name you can get it from

this code.

```
NSString * username = [FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine].authenticatedUsername;
```

using that username you can get whatever you want

```
 NSMutableDictionary *   dict1 = [[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]listFriendsForUser:username isID:NO withCursor:@"-1"];

    NSLog(@"====> %@",[dict1 objectForKey:@"users"] );        // Here You get all the data
    NSMutableArray *array=[dict1 objectForKey:@"users"];
    for(int i=0;i<[array count];i++)
    {
        NSLog(@"names:%@",[[array objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"name"]);

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this. Looks like you were trying to use old twitter api

```
 ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
 ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];
 [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error){
    if (granted) {
        NSArray *accounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];
        // Check if the users has setup at least one Twitter account
        if (accounts.count > 0)
        {
            ACAccount *twitterAccount = [accounts objectAtIndex:0];

            for(ACAccount *t in accounts)
            {
                if([t.username isEqualToString:username])
                {
                    twitterAccount = t;
                    break;
                }
            }

            SLRequest *twitterInfoRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET URL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friends/ids.json?"] parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", username], @"screen_name", @"-1", @"cursor", nil]];
            [twitterInfoRequest setAccount:twitterAccount];
            // Making the request
            [twitterInfoRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    // Check if we reached the reate limit
                    if ([urlResponse statusCode] == 429) {
                        NSLog(@"Rate limit reached");
                        return;
                    }
                    // Check if there was an error
                    if (error) {
                        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                        return;
                    }
                    // Check if there is some response data
                    if (responseData) {
                        NSError *error = nil;
                        NSArray *TWData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];


                    }
                });
            }];
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"No access granted");
    }
}];
```

Comment: Then you will need to request this (through paging) to get names   SLRequest *twitterUsersRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST URL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/lookup.json"] parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[first100 componentsJoinedByString:@","], @"user_id", @"false", @"include_entities", nil]];

Comment: please post the code.   and what is usename in this code. what should i passed here...

Comment: Here is my component (used a year ago, so may be some changes need to make) https://github.com/ArchieGoodwin/NWTwitterHelper

Comment: Yes, used this for some requests. Replace it or remove of course

Comment: There you can get it NSArray *accounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

Comment: If you mean the friends names then look at -(void)buildResult method in NWTwitterHelper

Comment: It is just code to check if account is equal to stored one.